# Confusion with scope in Python decorators

Tags: python, function, scope, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to make a simple Python decorator, below is a simplified example of my use case.

```
def decorator(x):
    def inner(f):
        if x == 2:
            x = 1
        return f
    return inner

@decorator(2)
def f():
    pass
```

But I get this error

```
if x == 2:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Why is `x` not available? It's confusing because if I use `print(x)` instead of `if x == 2` it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can't determine `x`s actual scope, so before it runs, in the `inner` function it would raise the `UnboundLocalError`.

The way to fix it is modify the arguments of `inner` a bit, instead of:

```
    def inner(f):
```

Make it to be:

```
    def inner(f, x=x):
```

Then your code would work fine.

Or you could also use `nonlocal`, by adding `nonlocal x` in the beginning of the function `inner`.

```
def inner(f):
    nonlocal x
    if x == 2:
        x = 1
    return f
```